# Using NUnit Multiple Assert when Assert statements are in different methods

Tags: c#, testing, automation, nunit, assert

I am running automated BDD steps using `NUnit` assertions for each step i.e. `Then` `And` for my UI tests.

The `NUnit` assertions are confined to confined to each method.  This means that if an assertion in a method fails, then the other steps won't be run.

I was thinking of using `NUnit Multiple Assert` but this requires all the asserts to be together.  Any ideas?

```
BDD Steps

Then I am shown results for("foo")
And the page count is(3)
```

I am using the `LightBDD` Library https://github.com/LightBDD/LightBDD

```cs
// Then Step
private void ThenIAmShownResultsFor(string expectedResults)
{
    Assert.AreEqual(expectedResults, actual);
}

// And Step
private void AndThePageCountIs(int expectedResults)
{
    Assert.AreEqual(expectedResults, actual);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See [this article](https://conductofcode.io/post/behavior-driven-development-with-nunit/). Your tests that are reliant on the result of another should mock those other tests or methods. Each test should be **completely** decoupled from any other tests. You should *never, ever, ever* make one test dependent on the results of another. If a test relies on the results of another, you need to mock the response from the other test.

The code, assuming _foo

```
// And Step
private void AndThePageCountIs(int expectedResults)
{
   actual = _foo.Setup(x => x.ThenIAmShownResultsFor()).Returns(expectedResults);
   Assert.AreEqual(expectedResults, actual);
}
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question.  My steps are independent of each other.

Comment: If one test failing is having *any effect whatsoever* on your other tests, then they aren't independent. Any number of tests should be able to fail without causing any other tests to fail. No test's execution should rely on the results or successful execution of another test. This would make the tests completely pointless. If something is wrong with the code, only that specific unit should fail. If they all fail, your tests are not describing the actual problem. If only one fails you know exactly which section of the code is causing the problem.The entire test suite fails, it tells you nothing

Comment: But,  I want assert each `Then` step.

Comment: Then you mock your `Given` step in your test for your `Then` step.